# why doesn't this routing work on heroku but works locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb file for **Rails 3**:

```
 13   namespace :user do
 14     root :to => "users#profile"
 15   end
```

I get this error on heroku:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::UsersController):
```

I already restarted the application.

I am doing this because I am using devise and this is what it says on the wiki:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: Does `User::UsersController` exist and is it in a sub-directory 'user' of your 'controllers' directory?

Comment: hmm...no there isn't...I did it because of the wiki and I posted it above....it is for using devise...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Rails is expecting there to be a controller within a module called `Users` because that's what `namespace :user` infers. Perhaps you meant to use `scope` instead of `namespace`?

```
scope :path => "user" do
  root :to => "users#profile"
end
```

Note: in this situation if you've only got one route it would not be wise to use `scope`, but if you've got multiple ones with the `/user` prefix then it would be fine to. If you only had one, I would do this instead:

```
get '/user', :to => "users#profile"
```

Comment: hmm, I did it that way because of what the wiki said (I put a link to it above in my revised q.

Comment: I think within the Devise gem there is a module named users...and then I can overwrite it y creating my own Users controller and adding the #profile action...but I don't know.....it's not working locally when i do this, though....ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku environments run in production mode. When you run locally, you run in development mode, which accounts for at least one difference. Try this instead:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s
```

and see if you notice the same error.

Comment: do you know why routes woiuld behave differently in production?