# Routing Error only on Heroku - not in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, routes

When I add something to my cart in my app, I get this error on Heroku:

```
Started POST "/cart/items" for XX.XXX.XXX.XX at 2013-11-25 17:52:12 +0000
2013-11-25T17:52:12.160587+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-25T17:52:12.160587+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Cart::CartItemsController):
2013-11-25T17:52:12.160587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

But when I do the same thing in development, I don't get any issues.

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
  namespace :cart do
    get '/', to: 'cart#index', as: 'index'
    match 'checkout', to: 'cart#checkout', as: 'checkout', via: [:post]
    resources :cart_items,
              path: :items, as: :items,
              only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

This is my `CartItemsController.rb`:

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  def create
    @cart_item = @cart.add_item(params[:item_id])
    redirect_to cart_index_path
  end

  def destroy
    @cart_item = @cart.remove_item(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Thoughts on what could be causing this?

**Edit 1**:

Add to Cart Form

```
 <%= form_tag(cart_items_path) do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag 'item_id', @item.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add to Cart (#{number_to_currency(@item.price, precision: 2)})", class: "btn btn-success btn-large" %>
 <% end %>
```

Rake Routes Output

```
cart_index_path  GET     /cart(.:format)     cart/cart#index
cart_checkout_path   POST    /cart/checkout(.:format)    cart/cart#checkout
cart_items_path  POST    /cart/items(.:format)   cart/cart_items#create
cart_item_path   DELETE  /cart/items/:id(.:format)   cart/cart_items#destroy
```

Comment: Can you post the form/link that adds the item to the cart?

Comment: And can you post "rake routes"

Comment: @fatfrog Done and done!

Comment: What happens on the site when you add to cart? Do you get any errors?

Comment: on Heroku, yes...on the redirect...I get a 404 error, but the logs show the error I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
#app/controllers/cart_items_controller.rb
class Cart::CartItemsController < ApplicationController

#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class Cart::CartController < ApplicationController
```

If you use a namespace, you have to delegate your controllers to the namespace. Don't know why - I learnt this from [this tutorial with namespaces](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1)

**Update**

As per the OP's comments, you should also look at these to accompany the above code:

- You should change the views directory structure to:
  `views/cart/cart/index.html.erb`

Comment: This definitely led me in the right direction. I then had to change the directory structure of the views to `views/cart/cart/index.html.erb` and also change the `Cart` controller to add the namespace. If you can add those tips, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Updated for you sir. If you provide code for the Cart controller, I'll put that up too

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 0):

Root should go at the bottom, as it is a catch all.

```
  namespace :cart do
    match 'checkout', to: 'cart#checkout', as: 'checkout', via: [:post]
    resources :cart_items,
              path: :items, as: :items,
              only: [:create, :destroy]
    get '/', to: 'cart#index', as: 'index'

  end
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658132/why-doesnt-this-routing-work-on-heroku-but-works-locally

Comment: And just to confirm, you have no routes above your route that can conflict?

Comment: Nope..that route is at the top of my `routes.rb`. It works in development, btw.